# How to add text on products?

Tags: texturing, uv

I want to add texts/labels to the product models I make. How do I do that? Using a *Shrinkwrap* modifier is one method but it is neither accurate nor satisfying. Another method is UV unwrapping but I don't know how to mix nodes to place texts exactly where I want without compromising the shader node underneath.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i would use the same bsdf, but an image texture with alpha and just the number. Then use mix rgb node to add the number. And you can even use bump to have a engraved text.

node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1 but the texture of the painting should not be the same as the object  :p

Comment: Yes, but you know that I am not a perfectionist 

Answer (score 5):

You can prepare your text on a transparent background, save as PNG, unwrap your object, mix 2 *Principled BSDF* in a *Mix Shader* with the alpha as factor, plug your image in the *Base Color* input of one of the *Principled BSDF*, keep your object black material for the other one:

[image]

As pointed out by Chris, to add a bit of bump to the text, create a normal map from your text image and plug it into a *Normal Map* that you plug into the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

Comment: very nice, but nooooo engraving as the old cameras do have ;) but +1 from me

Comment: oh yes you're right I've forgotten the engraving  ;)

Comment: not really...he didn't even ask for engraving :D